# Electronics Newbie : Can you switch from two voltage sources with a MOSFET?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, switching

Title and image describes it all, can you use one mosfet to switch two things with different voltages from one microcontroller pin?

[image]

Comment: Consider what would happen when the switch is off.

Comment: Almost all discrete MOSFETs have a parasitic body diode. You can see it in their schematic symbol. It means they can only *block* current in one direction, but can conduct current in *both* directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's connected to `J5` and `J12`.  Without knowing the details, I would say you'll likely have problems with J5 in this configuration when the FET is OFF.

Think about voltages with the FET off:  `J5, pin 1` would be +5V and `J5, pin 2` would be ~12V (through `J12`), and you'd have a -7V reverse voltage on the connected `J5` device.  If the `J5` device can tolerate a large reverse voltage, it might work, but not recommended at first glance.

Consider adding another FET controlled by the same GPIO line instead...

Comment: Weirdly I had not considered using another Mosfet controlled from the same GPIO... thank you!

Answer (score -1):

A FET and BJT alike are just single pole , single throw switches.(SPST or 1P1T) to a low V or ground (NPN or Nch) and high for PNP or Pch.  They are both inverting logic switches in common emitter or source.

It takes 2 to make a 2P1T or a 1P2T